# Drop down option aside table sub-menu under database menu in sidebar panel of workbench is not available

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, workbench

Here's the screenshot of the problem:

[image]

In the left the encircled table sub-menu, whose drop down option is not available and in the right, list of tables under that database.

Comment: Did you try the refresh button on the top right? The sub-menu gets cached, and isn't refreshed when the database changes (Until you hit that button)

Comment: yup, I refreshed it many times but it didn't worked

Comment: Try updating mysql-workbench. Verify the version is compatable.

Comment: Its already updated i.e., is of version 8.0.11 .

Comment: Take a look in the log file (Help Menu). There's probably something going wrong that prevents the table list in the schema tree to be filled. The schema inspector has an own connection with own queries to get the table information from the I_S.